# error related to white noise generation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, time-series

i have a problem and please help me to  fix it.suppose that we have following  data

```
f1=100;
 f2=200;
 T=1./f1;
 N=3;
 m=500;
 t=(0:(N*T)/m:(N*t))';
 wn=rand(length(t),1).*2-1;
```

but when i  tried to  see value  of  wn,it shows me following    one

```
0.6294
```

i need it  for following code

```
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
```

A3 is amplitude for white noise.but   main problem is  follwing

1.should not wn  be  array instead of scalar?

2.why it shows me the same value of wn  at each time i type wn?

as you see this is model of  two deterministic periodic  model +white noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=(0:(N*T)/m:(N*t))';
```

`t` is using itself in it's definition. That can't be right. I would suspect if you called `clear` and then run this script that line would error.

Comment: right right i saw it now,it should be T,i will upvote and accept your answer

Comment: right , i will accept this code and then post new one.with different  meaning.it needs 7 minute,so please wait

Comment: sorry  my friend for  wasting  your time.i  accepted your answer